# Quartz scheduler incorrect schedule time

Tags: java, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I have a spring boot application in which I am trying to schedule a job using quartz scheduler to run daily at a specific time of the day. The following is my code to build the trigger.

```
DailyTimeIntervalScheduleBuilder scheduleBuilder = DailyTimeIntervalScheduleBuilder
.dailyTimeIntervalSchedule()
.startingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.hourAndMinuteFromDate(activeStartTime))
.endingDailyAfterCount(1)
.withMisfireHandlingInstructionFireAndProceed();

MutableTrigger trigger = scheduleBuilder.build();
```

The problem I am facing is that the job is scheduled but starting from the next day. So for instance, if I schedule the job for **May 22 16:45**, then the first fire time for the job is set to **May 23 16:45**.

I have tried using the builder with **`withIntervalInHours(24)`** instead of **`endingDailyAfterCount(1)`**, but the result is the same.

I am not sure what seems to be the problem.

***Note:*** This behavior is the same regardless of when I schedule my job, i.e., it doesn't matter if I execute this code before or after 16:45, the job is always scheduled for the next day

I am using spring boot version **1.5.10** and spring-boot-starter-quartz version **2.2.5.RELEASE**

Answer (score 1):

Can you try below code

```
CalendarIntervalScheduleBuilder schedule = CalendarIntervalScheduleBuilder
                .calendarIntervalSchedule()
                .inTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault())
                .withIntervalInDays((int) 1)
                .withMisfireHandlingInstructionFireAndProceed();

Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
                .newTrigger()
                .startAt(startDateTime)
                .withSchedule(schedule).build();
```

For the field `startDateTime` please use current Date time. if you want to start from `May 22 16:45` then create the `Date` object accordingly.

And set the `timezone` also, or it will pick default system's timezone.